# iOS app size: over-the-air vs. wi-fi

Tags: ios, filesize, cellular-network

TL;DR: Is the size message I got in App Store Connect just a warning, or do I need special permission (some checkbox?) to go past the size limit.

I understand that the over-the-air size is limited to 150 MB (latest limit) and the wi-fi size is limited to 2 GB. This is well-explained here on SO and other places.

Now... the last time I submitted an app that was over the limit I got this warning (or is it fatal error?):

[image: Size limit warning]

(Yeah it says 100 MB: it's an old screen shot.) So the question is: when my next submission goes over 150 MB (as it surely will) and I get this message again, what to do?

- Just proceed with approval process?
- Check some box somewhere
  acknowledging that users won't be able to use their cellular
  connection to download?
- Get some permission?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, 100MB is the limit for cellular download. You can submit your app and it won't affect your approval, but users will not be able to download your app unless they are on Wifi.

However, a common solution to this problem is to perform a one-time download of large files the first time your app is launched. That way, you can still have all of those files, but your initial app store download will be within the download limit.

You can also use app thinning to reduce your file size or move some of your larger resources to on demand storage. Apple has given you links to both of those methods in that warning message you posted.

Comment: Already using bitcode (for thinning) and ODR. (The app is a freemium model with additional resources buyable via in-app purchase.) I believe there is a race condition in `conditionallyBeginAccessingResources` that kept freezing my app. Spent weeks trying to debug it. Switching to supplying resources via AWS fixed the problem.

Comment: To forestall well-intended advice about iOS ODR, see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43202. It's an ongoing pain point. If you thought the write-compile-debug cycle was slow, don’t even think about the build-upload-download-debug cycle.